# Can I enhance a bounty using reputation from another Stack Exchange site?

Tags: support, bounty

I set a bounty of 100 to one of my questions on Stack Overflow. As getting a good answer is very important to me, and I have very few points available on my Stack Overflow account, I was wondering if it is possible to enhance the bounty using reputation from my Ask Ubuntu account where I have more points.

Comment: You already got 100 reputation points on your stack overflow account thanks to having high reputation elsewhere. That's enough to give you a head start. Spend 30 minutes answering questions on stack overflow and you'll have plenty of rep for your bounty.

Answer (score 8):

No, you cannot currently do this. Reputation cannot be transferred from one site to another, even for the purposes of bountying a question.

A cross-site bounty feature [has previously been proposed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7193/allow-bounty-to-be-set-with-reputation-from-another-site)—many times, actually—but it was declined by the Stack Exchange team.

Probably the best explanation of why this would be problematic is given by Martijn Pieters on [this duplicate feature request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/216975/can-i-borrow-points-from-one-stackexchange-account-for-a-bounty-on-another):

> No, each site is essentially isolated from the other sites, as far as reputation is concerned. You cannot transfer bounties from reputation earned elsewhere.
>
> The only exception is the association bonus which is given to you because you've learned the basics of the Stack Exchange model.
>
> If you *could* transfer reputation, then anyone with an account on a busy site such as Stack Overflow could monopolize attention on a smaller site. I could use my 200k on Stack Overflow to buy a lot of eyeballs over on, say, Pets.stackexchange.com. That would not be fair to the other regular Pets supporters without a big fat SO account to draw from.

Comment: Very good quote. Must admit I didn't think about it before reading. Must be my naive side of not thinking how to abuse these systems.